# Separate "document" in appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm not that familiar with LaTeX and have a problem with the structure of my document. The table of contents has been created with "\tableofcontents", the appendix with "\appendix" (no further commands for both of them, they are filled completely automatically). In the appendix I have a subsection "MyDocument" which should represent a logically separate document (but actually I want to write in the same tex file). Only the subsection name should appear in the table of contents, not more (normally it would also include one hierarchy layer below). Within this subsection I have three further layers of hierarchy which should be numbered without the appendix prefix "A".

**So, the toc should look like this:**

1 Chapter

2 Chapter

...

A Appendix

A.1 One appendix

A.2 MyDocument

A.3 Another appendix

**The subsection "MyDocument"** is placed in a separate tex file (included into appendix) and should look like this (all headings numbered and formatted as headings):

A.2 My Document

1 abc

1.1 hello

1.2 world

1.2.1 world A

1.2.2 world B

2 xyz

**Edit: some code**

**main document**

```
...
\tableofcontents

\include{chapters/chapter1}

\include{chapters/chapter2}

\appendix 

\include{general/appendix}
```

**appendix.tex**

```
\section{Appendix}

\input{appendices/one}

\input{appendices/mydocument}

\input{appendices/another}
```

**mydocument.tex**

```
\subsection{My Document}

\subsubsection{abc}

\paragraph{hello}

\paragraph{world}

\subparagraph{world 1}

\subparagraph{world 2}

\subsubsection{xyz}
```

I found a static solution which is not very comfortable, but ok for my case (I'm mainly interested in the pre-formatted headings, but I don't want the structure of mydocument appear in the table of contents): Remove automated numbering and adding to the toc, use hard-coded numbers instead (probably not a good idea if the structure of this document changes, but in this special case it really is fixed)

> \subsubsection*{1. abc}

etc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a minimal code which shows your case? It needs some time to reproduce your problem but we would prefer, just to solve it. Thanks. PS: how shall your ToC handle "1 Chapter" and "1 abc"? That's does not seem very intuitive to read.

Comment: The minitoc manual (which had to be downloaded separately) says: Some users need a table of contents for the appendices, but without putting the entries of it
into the main table of contents. The solution is to put the appendices in a \part subdivision
of the document and ask for a table of contents at the \part level:

Comment: LaTeXFan: See my possible solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the names of the files and the structure slightly, for sake of easyness to provide a solution.

The standard macro `\addcontentsline` is responsible for the generation of ToC entries. If something should not be added to the ToC, but numbered anyway, it's better to kick out the meaning of `\addcontentsline` for while inside `mydocument.tex`. This is most easily done with a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair right after `\subsection{MyDocument}`.
Any redefinition of a command or length changes, counter formatting is only done with such a group and does not affect the outside code.

Please have a look on the ToC, that `\section{Another appendix}` behaves as usual whereas the `Minidocument` subsection has its own counter formatting,but is numbered by default, without hard-coding.

**Remark**
If a `book` or `report` class is used, `\appendix` behaves best with `\chapter` subdivisions, not with `\sections` as top level structure units.

### main.tex -- the main document frame

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

%\include{chapters/chapter1}

%\include{chapters/chapter2}

\chapter{chapter1}
\chapter{chapter2}

\appendix 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\input{appendixcontent} 


\end{document}
```

### appendixcontent.tex

```
\section{Appendix}

\InputIfFileExists{one}{}{}%

\InputIfFileExists{mydocument}{}{}%

\InputIfFileExists{another}{}%

\section{Another appendix}%
```

### mydocument.tex

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begingroup
\subsection{My Document}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Do nothing

\subsubsection{abc}

\paragraph{hello}

\paragraph{world}

\subparagraph{world 1}

\subparagraph{world 2}

\subsubsection{xyz}

\endgroup
```

### ToC without using the structure of the faked mini document

[image]

### Structure of faked document

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of solution I've been looking for!

Comment: Ok, happy TeXing then... I only want to suggest to use `\chapters` in \appendix` but that's a matter of taste, actually